# Conversion of a tree to a new tree with p as its new root

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree

The actual question is :

> Write a program that takes as input a general tree T and a position p of T and converts T to another tree with the same set of position adjacencies, but now with p as its root.

I am not sure what does it means by the position adjacencies exactly but from what I understood is that the relation between the parent as the nodes should be maintained.

But if a node is made to be the root then they wont be having the same positional adjacency. I would like to implement this question using a binary tree for starters.

Can someone help me out with how should I implement it?

Comment: Can you provide context to the question? There is no standard definition of "position" in the context of trees, so you'll have to get that from the book/course/website where you quote this from.

Comment: @trincot This was the only thing I got from it, I too was trying to identify the definition for the same, but since it was not mentioned anywhere explicitly, I assumed it to be the node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quote uses some terms which should be further defined, but I will try to make some assumptions here:

> > ...but now with p as its root.

This implies that the tree given as input is a so-called *rooted* tree and not just a *general* tree as it states at the outset. It is important to note this, as in graph theory a tree is just a graph where each pair of nodes is connected by a single path. The concept of root only enters the story when we speak of a *rooted* tree.

> > ...a position p of T...

This is uncommon terminology. I'll assume that *position* is a synonym for what is generally called a *vertex* or *node* in graph theory.

> > ... position adjacencies

I'll assume that this is referring to the *edges* of the tree.

> ... the relation between the parent as the nodes should be maintained.

If you phrase it that way, then it is impossible to change the tree, as the set of parent-child relationships uniquely defines the rooted tree. So we must assume that this is not about maintaining the parent-child relationship, but just the relationship between two vertices, where possibly the role of parent may be changing.

> I would like to implement this question using a binary tree for starters.

That is not a good idea: a binary tree may need to transition to a non-binary tree. For example, let's say the input tree is this binary tree:

```
                4
               /
              2
             / \
            1   3
```

And the input vertex is the one with value 2. That means the output tree will not be binary, but will be:

```
               2
              /|\
             1 3 4
```

So, we have a rooted tree and a vertex in that tree as input, and need to produce a rooted tree as output whose root is that given vertex.

## Algorithm

The algorithm can be recursive:

- If the given node `p` (that should become the root) has no parent, nothing needs to change: exit
- Solve the problem of making that parent the root recursively. Once that is done the `p`'s parent has no parent, since `p`'s parent has become the root.
- Detach `p` from its parent, and instead make that parent a child of `p`. So these two nodes remain connected, but the role of parent-child switches to child-parent.

Here is an implementation in JavaScript. You can run the snippet here on an example graph:

```
                  8
                 / \
                4   10
               /
              2  <-- to become new root
             / \
            1   3
```

Resulting tree should be:

```
              2
             /|\
            1 3 4
                 \
                  8
                   \
                    10
```

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.children = new Set; // any number of children
        this.parent = null;
    }
    addChild(node) {
        this.children.add(node);
        node.parent = this; // back reference
        return node;
    }
    detachFromParent() {
        if (this.parent != null) {
            this.parent.children.delete(this);
            this.parent = null;
        }
    }
    makeRoot() {
        let parent = this.parent; 
        if (parent != null) {
            parent.makeRoot();
            this.detachFromParent();
            this.addChild(parent);
        }
    }
    print(indent="") {
        console.log(indent + this.value);
        indent += "  ";
        for (const child of this.children) {
            child.print(indent);
        }
    }
}

// demo
let eight = new Node(8);
let ten = new Node(10);
let four = new Node(4);
let two = new Node(2);
let one = new Node(1);
let three = new Node(3);
eight.addChild(four);
eight.addChild(ten);
four.addChild(two);
two.addChild(one);
two.addChild(three);

console.log("input:");
eight.print();

console.log("change root to 2...");
two.makeRoot();
two.print();
```